# AVCaptureSession detect QR code with transformation angles

Tags: qr-code, augmented-reality

I am able to detect QRCode using AVCaptureSession and AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode. My question is can I also detect the transforming angle at which the QRcode appears on camera output, so that I can place an image on my view with same transformation angle?

Comment: I got my answer,                                                                                            let tarnsformed = _previewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) gave me what I wanted....

Comment: Can you please post how to calculate the transformation angle.